# vsts - newly created iteration does not appear on taskboard

Tags: azure-devops

When I add a new iteration in VSTS, it does not appear in the backlog explorer (=left navigation). 
It is available in the Iteration Combobox of a workitem, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that there is another "default team's settings" page, where the newly created iteration also needs to be added.
[image: screenshot]